# Osmdroid -NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay.onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a problem with my app, which includes osmdroid. Every time I try to run the app on my device and touch the map, the app crashs and I'm getting this error:

```
    2018-10-02 14:11:45.191 19645-19645/com.message_drop.messagedrop E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2018-10-02 14:11:45.191 19645-19645/com.message_drop.messagedrop E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2018-10-02 14:11:45.196 19645-19645/com.message_drop.messagedrop E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, org.osmdroid.views.MapView)' on a null object reference
        at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onTouchEvent(DefaultOverlayManager.java:214)
        at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchTouchEvent(MapView.java:1050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:552)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1959)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3530)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:505)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12082)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5325)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4769)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4826)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7222)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7157)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7379)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:193)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7377)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
2018-10-02 14:11:45.196 19645-19645/com.message_drop.messagedrop D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-10-02 14:11:45.201 19645-19645/com.message_drop.messagedrop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.message_drop.messagedrop, PID: 19645
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, org.osmdroid.views.MapView)' on a null object reference
        at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onTouchEvent(DefaultOverlayManager.java:214)
        at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchTouchEvent(MapView.java:1050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2981)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2611)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:552)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1959)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3530)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:505)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12082)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5325)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4769)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4826)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7222)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7157)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7379)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:193)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7377)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

I don't know how to handle this error and I hope that somebody can help me. I already looked for solutions on the internet, but didn't found any.
If you need more code please just let me know.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, View.OnClickListener {

    MapView mapView;
    MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    String content = "a";
    String author = "b";
    Double latitude = 53.2;
    Double longitude = 11.5;
    private ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> messagesOverlay;
    private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private long totalNumberChilds;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set up the mapView and show the MyLocationOverlay
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(5);
        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(getApplicationContext()), mapView);
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(messagesOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        GeoPoint point = this.myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        if(point==null){
            return;
        } else {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
        }

        //initialize the Overlay for the Messages
        messagesOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.briefumschlag), null, this);

        //messagesOverlay.addItem(new OverlayItem(author, "", new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)));

        //declare the database variables in onCreate
        //NOTE: Unless you are signed in, this will not be useable.
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                messagesOverlay.removeAllItems();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yesss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Message message = new Message();
                    //String author1 = ds.child("messageAuthor").getValue(String.class);
                    /*String content1 = ds.child("messageContent").getValue(String.class);
                    Double latitude1 = ds.child("messageLatitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double longitude1 = ds.child("messageLongitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    messagesOverlay.addItem(new OverlayItem("by" + author1, "", new GeoPoint(latitude1, longitude1)));*/

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.testButton) {
            addMessage();
        }
    }

    public void addMessage() {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        String id = myRef.push().getKey();

        Message message = new Message(author, content, latitude, longitude);

        myRef.child(id).setValue(message);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Message added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(location);
        if(point==null){
            return;
        } else {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

My LoginActivity.java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private EditText tfEmail, tfPassword;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        tfEmail = findViewById(R.id.tfEmail);
        tfPassword = findViewById(R.id.tfPassword);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    //User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in" + user.getUid());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully signed in with:" + user.getEmail(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully signed out.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSignIn) {
            String email = tfEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = tfPassword.getText().toString();
            if (!email.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSignOut) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signing Out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


}
```

My Message.java:

```
public class Message {

    String messageAuthor;
    String messageContent;
    Double messageLatitude;
    Double messageLongitude;

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(String messageAuthor, String messageContent, Double messageLatitude, Double messageLongitude) {
        this.messageAuthor = messageAuthor;
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
        this.messageLatitude = messageLatitude;
        this.messageLongitude = messageLongitude;
    }

    public String getMessageAuthor() {
        return messageAuthor;
    }

    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }

    public Double getMessageLatitude() {
        return messageLatitude;
    }

    public Double getMessageLongitude() {
        return messageLongitude;
    }

    public void setMessageAuthor(String messageAuthor) {
        this.messageAuthor = messageAuthor;
    }

    public void setMessageContent(String messageContent) {
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
    }

    public void setMessageLatitude(Double messageLatitude) {
        this.messageLatitude = messageLatitude;
    }

    public void setMessageLongitude(Double messageLongitude) {
        this.messageLongitude = messageLongitude;
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/testButton"
            android:text="add"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

and my activity_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tfEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And one thing I should mention is, that before I added the LoginActivity class the map worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Which osmdroid version? Did you already try a different release?

Comment: probably you are touching before overlay has been initialized. in order to get better help, always put the java code and xml code along with the stacktrace

Comment: I'm using the osmdroid version 6.0.2 and yes I already tried a different release

Comment: sorry, I added the code of my app now

Comment: Hi @huhn3k , welcome to stackoverflow. It's great that you added the code, now we can actually see the problem and I have already posted an answer. Next time you can try to add just the relevant code, it's not necessary to add source code for whole application. Please read a little bit about [MCVE here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I understand that it may be hard to know what is actually a relevant part of code to the problem you have, if it's the case, don't worry. Just try to guess the most important thing and we will tell you if we need to see more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check carefully your onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set up the mapView and show the MyLocationOverlay
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    //... shortened ...
    mapView.getOverlays().add(messagesOverlay); // <== here you are adding null, the messagesOevrlay variable is not yet initialized
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    //..shortened...


    // here you are creating the instance
    messagesOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.briefumschlag), null, this);
```

You should either move the line where you create the instance before those calls to  `getOverlays().add()` or move the `getOverlays().add(messagesOverlay)` down.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. I can't believe it was such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @huhn3k Happy to help. And don't worry, everybody overlooks something sometimes. You can also [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), since it's correct.